# Mailer Error: SMTP connect()

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-7

> Essa classe foi criado para enviar as informação da compra do produto para a caixa de email, mas um erro ("Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting")

```
<?php

class EnviarEmail extends PHPMailer {
    /**
   * inicializa a classe com os dados iniciais
   * @return void
   */
    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        // defino que é SMTP        
        parent::IsSMTP();
                // se é em HTML
    parent::IsHTML(true);
                 // codificação charset padrao UTF8
        $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        // modo debug 0=off 1 e 2=mostram informações do envio ou erros
        $this->SMTPDebug = 0;
        //Indica a porta do seu servidor
        $this->Port = Config::EMAIL_PORTA; 
        //smtp.dominio.com.br //seu servidor smtp
        $this->Host = Config::EMAIL_HOST; 
        //define se tem ou autenticação no SMTP
        $this->SMTPAuth = Config::EMAIL_SMTPAUTH; 
                // define dados do remetendo EMAIL, SENHA  da conta SMTP
        $this->FromName    = Config::EMAIL_NOME;
        $this->From        = Config::EMAIL_USER;
        $this->Username    = Config::EMAIL_USER;
        $this->Password    = Config::EMAIL_SENHA;

    }

    /** * Envia o email propriamente dito
   * @return void
   * $setor = setor , $destinatario=email dominio, assunto, msg
         * $reply = email que vai a resposta 
         */ 
    function Enviar($assunto, $msg, $destinatarios=array()) {

                  //seto dados da mensagem
        $this->Subject      = $assunto;
        $this->Body         = $msg;

                // email de resposta
                //  $this->AddReplyTo($reply);
                // email para receber  uma cópia
     //   $this->Addcc(Config::EMAIL_COPIA);

                 //passando um laço para pegar todos os destinatarios       
        foreach($destinatarios as $email):

                $this->AddAddress($email, $email); //PARA MIM

            endforeach;

                 //enviando o email 
            if (parent::Send()):

                $this->ClearAllRecipients();

            else:
            echo "<h4>Mailer Error: " . $this->ErrorInfo . "</h4>";

            endif;
    }    


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser n coisas, já tive problemas com conexão SMTP há um tempo, faz o seguinte:

1- Mudar o valor do SMTPDebug para 1 ou 2 p/ ver se a conexão te diz exatamente onde está dando erro, ler a pilha de erro é fundamental e as vezes nos poupa muito tempo;

2- verificar se o EMAIL_HOST está correto, se tiver usando gmail o stmp é esse -> smtp.gmail.com, se não for, verifica o endereço correto de acordo com o email que tu está utilizando, na porta 587

3- Ainda falando em gmail, se tiver usando é claro, habilita a opção "Acesso a app menos seguros"

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Outra coisa que percebi é que não está passando o $mail->SMTPSecure, ele é importante para habilitar a encriptação TLS

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
```

Comment: Eu já fiz todos esses procedimentos antes do gmail, mas mesmo assim continua apresentando o mesmo erro

Answer (score 0):

Isto significa que os parâmetros do servidor de email (Config::EMAIL_HOST e similares) não apontam para um servidor SMTP funcional. O problema não parece ser no código postado.